# Python - Loop Through List A and Match Words Contained in List B

Tags: python, arrays, loops

Let's say I have two lists:

```
foo = ['hell', 'good', 'bad']
bar = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'goodness', 'badly', 'baddest']
```

I'd like to sort through foo and see if any word in bar not just matches but contains foo, to get something  like:

```
hell = hello
good = goodbye goodness
bad = badly baddest
```

Comment: Just as a note, these are tuples, not lists. Which vary largely in that tuples are immutable.

Comment: They are also missing quotation marks, unless `hell, good, etc.` are all variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
one = ['hell','good','bad']
two = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'goodness', 'badly', 'baddest']

for a in one:
    print a,'=',
    for b in two:
        if a in b:
            print b,
    print
```

Output:

```
hell = hello
good = goodbye goodness
bad = badly baddest
```

Comment: epic and exactly what I need as output! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Very simple problem, many ways to approach it. Here's a version that doesn't print out the 'equals' line if there are no matches:

```
foo = ["hell", "good", "bad", "fail"]
bar = ["hello", "goodbye", "goodness", "badly", "baddest", "nomatch"]

for f in foo:
    matches = [b for b in bar if f in b]
    if len(matches) > 0:
        print(f,"="," ".join(matches))
```

Output:

```
hell = hello
good = goodbye goodness
bad = badly baddest
```

Notice that it doesn't output 'fail'. If you'd rather it printed the word 'fail', delete the `if` statement. The code could even then be reduced to one line, although I think it's a pretty unreadable single line:

```
[print(f,"="," ".join(b for b in bar if f in b)) for f in foo]
```

Comment: Thanks, although a generator inside a list comprehension isn't exactly the most readable thing ;)